# Send visible/filtered rows via SheetConverter and sendEmail in Google Sheets

Tags: vba, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have sheet in Google and want to create macro/script, which send only visible (filtered) row, f.e. rows to be checked.

In this case I want to send via SheetConverter (https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/sheetconverter) only rows with:

- in row A - Nr rej. poj. only filtered ZYX value,
- in row F - 09:00 only rows with value 5.

[image]

Could you change this for that conditions?

```
function sendEmail() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var document = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Raport - spedytorzy'), true);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  var dataraportu1 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm")
  var subject = '[RAPORT - GODZINOWY] Pojazdy własne' + ' ' + dataraportu1}

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Raport - spedytorzy'), true);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  var to = "xxx.xxx.pl";
  var name = "XXX";
  var body = '';

  var range = sheet.getRange('A:F');
  var htmlTable = SheetConverter.convertRange2html(range);
  var body = htmlTable
  GmailApp.sendEmail(to, subject, body,{name: name, htmlBody: body}); 
};
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Select filtered rows

- An easy solution is to implement a `for` loop that loops through your data and selects the rows that fulfill your criteria.
- Those rows can be pushed into a new array
- If the usage of SheetConverter requires a sheet range rather than a value array, you can e.g. assign the filtered values to an auxiliary sheet
- Below is a sample creating a new range with filtered rows in the auxiliary sheet "template" (that you need to create first) and passing the new range to SheeConverter.

```
function sendEmail() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Raport - spedytorzy');
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();
  var filteredValues = [];
  if(values.length!=0){
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

      if (values[i][0]=="ZYX" && values[i][5]==5) {
        Logger.log("yes");
        filteredValues.push(values[i]);
      }
    }
    var template = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("template");
    template.clear();
    if(filteredValues.length!=0){
      var templateRange = template.getRange(1,1, filteredValues.length, filteredValues[0].length);
      templateRange.setValues(filteredValues); 
      var dataraportu1 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm")
      var subject = '[RAPORT - GODZINOWY] Pojazdy własne' + ' ' + dataraportu1;
      var to = "xxx.xxx.pl";
      var name = "XXX";
      var body = '';
      var range = templateRange;
      var htmlTable = SheetConverter.convertRange2html(range);
      var body = htmlTable;
      GmailApp.sendEmail(to, subject, body,{name: name, htmlBody: body}); 
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I have error "TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (wiersz 57, plik „makra”)"

Comment: I think that "var filteredValues = [];" should be "[[]]".
But if i correct this, I have error:
"The number of columns in the range must be at least 1."
in
    var templateRange = template.getRange(1,1, filteredValues.length, filteredValues[0].length);

Comment: What is in you line 57? `var filteredValues` does not need to be `[[]]` - you assign it the second dimension when pushing a row of values into it.

Comment: Lane 57: var templateRange = template.getRange(1,1, filteredValues.length, filteredValues[0].length).setValues(filteredValues);

Comment: 1. If I gave [] it was an error - "TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (wiersz 57, plik „makra”)". Lane 57 I posted up. 
********
2. If I gave [[]] it was an error - The number of columns in the range must be at least 1. (wiersz 57, plik „makra”). Lane 57 I posted up.

Comment: This error can occur if no rows fulfilling your criteria have been found. You can catch it with an additional `if` statement - see my updated answer.